# Is there a way to use an array formula in conjunction with a filter view and sort by date

Tags: google-sheets

I've placed some ArrayFormulas to be hided under the header line (row 21) which are getting out of function when filter view (created filter view from the option bar at the top) is activated and if the column "Nächste Prüfung ➔ *12:00 Uhr *spätestens" (date) is sortet ascending.

The problem is, that I need for each user (~25) filter views to be filtered and sorted by user name and the mentined column (date).

Is there any way except for using standard formulas (if, then, else) instead of ArrayFormulas to solve the problem?

It's very important that the performance keeps well, because he table is shared with up to 25 users.

Here is a link to a copy of the table with reduced content. The problem I have with the sheet "Geprüfte Ticker".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1St5EWwjIJwW0RmOMXkhEKqS01Bcms0rzWELNctoDaFc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what do you mean by "skip rows"?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke the title. Now it  should be more clear. The problem occures after I sort by date ascending the column called „Nächste Prüfung ➔ *12:00 Uhr*spätestens“. Then all the ArrayFormulas in the row 21 are crashed. If I just sort by name the column called „Prüfer“ the ArrayFormulas are still working. The problem is I need both.

Comment: is this what you experience? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1D7s.png (if not, can you show me on screenshot?)

Comment: Correct. As can be seen on your screenshot the array formulas are crashed.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid scrambling of the array formulas you just need to move them beyond the reach of filter view like:

[image: 0]

(check your demo sheet)

Comment: Thanks to the solution. Unfortunately the calculation of the weekday gets confused when sorting by date.

Comment: can I see a screenshot of it?

Comment: In the demo sheet I created 2 tabs called sorted and unsorted where you can find screenshots. I dont know how i can upload a screenshot to a comment.

Comment: I guess the sorted one is the wrong one, right? but why/how - what should be the desired output?

Comment: Let's take the unsorted line with the username "denpei" (column A) and the "symbol" AABA (column C) from the screenshots as an example. In this line a check date has been entered in column K. From this I then calculate the date of the next check (column N) using the time stamp (column L) and the determined weekday (column M). These data are all connected and should therefore remain together line by line. But obviously the array formula for determining the weekday (column M) after sorting does not seem to work correctly, which leads to the wrong calculation of the next check date (column N).

Comment: I fixed the M20 cell/formula test it now pls

Comment: Unfortunately, the array formulas do not work when column N is sorted by  A-Z. The results of the formulas are still getting  confused. Therefore I decided to use standard formulas instead of array formulas. Thank you anyway.